# Cleaning up an HG repo

Tags: mercurial

**The goal**: Create a new repository without the unnecessary files which take 1.27 GB

**The solution:** Using hg convert and excluding the files

**The problem:** Files are not getting excluded

**Filemap.txt content:**

```
exclude "feturehub/wp-content/uploads/backupbuddy_backups"
exclude "feturehub/wp-content/uploads/edd/2015"
```

**The command**

```
hg convert --filemap filemap.txt featurehub featurehubclean
```

is being run from the parent folder of featurehub (src), src also contains the filemap.txt

What I get is a folder with only the .hg folder and in it the edd folder I'm trying to exclude (it's the same if edd OR its' 2015 subfolder get excluded, 2015 is the only thing in the edd folder).

**Edit:** Removed the third line in filemap.txt since it doesn't influence the result but it does cause confusion.

**Edit2:**

```
// fe is my source root, no there's no hg repo here, and each folder IS 
// a project with an hg repo, featurehub is one such project/repo

AndrijaMBA:fe ajambrovic$ ls | grep file
filemap.txt

AndrijaMBA:fe ajambrovic$ hg convert --filemap filemap.txt featurehub featurehubclean

initializing destination featurehubclean repository
scanning source...
sorting...
converting...
.....
```

After running the command, the new repo, featurehubclean, contains the edd folder (and its subfolders).

Comment: From what I remember about using hg convert - one doesn't specify files in the .hg folder (in the filemap).  Also the empty folder apart from the .hg folder is expected - one needs to do a "hg update" to update the working directory.

Comment: Adding to Tom's comment: Anything inside the .hg folder is the *actual* repository, but nothing inside there is being or can be tracked. The resulting repository of a convert run is a *bare* repository (thus only the .hg folder) with no revision *checked out*... just check-out a revision, if you desire so. Un-confuse yourself by understanding the difference between working dir state and repository

Comment: @Tom - could be, but I have a path to the folder and the problem is that the new repo still contains that folder, I've added a path to inside .hg just to see if it helps - it doesn't. The fact that the new directory is empty is not a problem, the fact that the new repo has the folder I'm trying to exclude is.

Comment: @planetmaker - I am unconfused, see previous comment ;)

Comment: Run `hg convert` *outside* any repository path. Is 'feturehub' a subdir as found in your repository? the filemap.txt must be local to the folder in which you run the convert command, thus preferentially *outside* any repository, at the same dir level where your repository dirs are found. I suspect you give it an empty filemap.txt, and the one you want to see used is somewhere else, e.g. in the working dir of your repo

Comment: I've updated the question because it wasn't readable when posted in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is trivial - paths. Instead of:

```
exclude "feturehub/wp-content/uploads/backupbuddy_backups"
exclude "feturehub/wp-content/uploads/edd/2015"
```

I should have used

```
exclude "wp-content/uploads/backupbuddy_backups"
exclude "wp-content/uploads/edd/2015"
```

The example here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/reduce-repository-size-321848262.html shows using (in this case) "featurehub", even though the extension documentation states:

> All paths should be specified as **relative paths rooted in the
>   converted directory**. Unix path syntax should be used, regardless of
>   OS.